# Finding the first time a variable is mentioned in multiple arrays

Tags: arrays, sas

I have a number of variables, `Location1-Location10`. I then have `Street1-Street10` as well.

I know this problem is likely answered with some sort of array but I'm not particularly sure how I would go about doing it. What I'm looking for is the first instance of "Home" being mentioned in `Location1-Location10` and then that "Home" values corresponding street in `Street1-Street10`.

I know that in the database as an example that if Home is found in `Location3` its street will be in `Street3`. I don't care if "Home" appears after the initial first time its mentioned (there are other things in the location as well- example: Work, School, etc.). Ultimately I'm looking at knowing the street - so if I could take the corresponding street name and place it into another new column that would be excellent (as I want to do a frequency after the fact). Any ideas how I do this?

Comment: Please post example input & output data, and any code you've already tried.

Answer (score 0):

Use the whichC function. You can probably nest these but I'll leave it expanded for easier understanding:

```
array loc(10) location1-location10;
array add(10) addresss1-address10;

index=whichc('Home', of loc(*));
home_address=add(index);
```

Comment: This works if the exact value 'home' is in the location - it's unclear to me if he means the exact value or if it is a free text that may have "Home Address", "Home Mailing Address", "My Home", etc. in it... probably worth mentioning (and a bit of explanation for what whichc does?).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion- I do mean that "Home" is the observation and exact value I'm looking for. Location can have a number of different words in it (ex: Home, School, Work) - its not free text, but there are quite a few categories. I'm just interested in Home.

Answer (score 0):

(Perhaps some sorting beforehand)

```
DATA your-dataset;  
  SET your-dataset;
  array location[10] location1-location10;    
  array street[10] street1-home10;   
  DO i = 1 to dim(location);    
    IF location[i] = "Home" THEN someVar = Street[i];    
  END;
Run;
```